# How do I use Tab to move between properties of winform property grid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

I am using Winform's `PropertyGrid` in my project, it all works fine but the tab order.

I want to switch to next property when I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> but infact, selection moves out of property grid to next control. I am not able to figure out how to get this done ?

Thanks

Comment: The only thing that is stopping me from posting the solution is a way to get the next visible item (from outside the current group of items). Everything else seems fine from my side.

Comment: There is a commercial solution that handles Tab key well. Is it an option for you?

Comment: thanks Nic, but I don't think that is an option just now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We should dig into internal parts of `PropertyGrid` then we can change default <kbd>Tab</kbd> behavior of control. At start we should create a derived `PropertyGrid` and override its [`ProcessTabKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.processtabkey(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

In the method, first find the internal [`PropertyGridView`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PropertyGridInternal/PropertyGridView.cs,e199112fb0a78323) control which is at index 2 in `Controls` collection. Then using [`Reflection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656691.aspx) get its `allGridEntries` field which is a collection containing all [`GridItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.griditem(v=vs.110).aspx) elements.

After finding all grid items, find the index of [`SelectedGridItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.selectedgriditem(v=vs.110).aspx) in the collection and check if it's not the last item, get the next item by index and select it using [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.griditem.select(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the item.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class ExPropertyGrid : PropertyGrid
{
    protected override bool ProcessTabKey(bool forward)
    {
        var grid = this.Controls[2];
        var field = grid.GetType().GetField("allGridEntries",
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        var entries = (field.GetValue(grid) as IEnumerable).Cast<GridItem>().ToList();
        var index = entries.IndexOf(this.SelectedGridItem);

        if (forward && index < entries.Count - 1)
        {
            var next = entries[index + 1];
            next.Select();
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessTabKey(forward);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Reza, but somehow ProcessTabKey is not hit when I press Tab.

Comment: Probably you have made a mistake. You should add this class to your project and put an instance of it on your form. I tested it and it I'me sure it works properly, so let me know if you have any problem applying the answer :)

Comment: yea  Reza that's what I have done, may be tab is handled elsewhere and doesn't let processTab execute ? I don't know what is the order of processing tab key but something is stopping tab to not propogate

Comment: It's good to test it in a clean form/project and let me know the result :)

Comment: I also tested it again in visual studio 2010 and visual studio 2013 :) Make sure you are dropping the new control we created **`ExPropertyGrid`** control on the form not the original property grid.

Comment: Hi Reza, I got this working partially as this PropertyGrid is hosted inside WPF Control hence I guess there are some issues, but one thing I wanted to check, if I press tab, it selects Property Name not the Value, can I make it select value everytime I press tab ?

Comment: Hi Muds, I don't have any idea about why it doesn't work properly in WPF, you may want to ask another question about that. About selecting the next label using `Tab`. What is the expected behavior when the focus is on label part of a property. What't the expected behavior when the focus in on value part of a property? Let me know and I'll check for it's feasibility :)

Comment: I think the best would be to always move focus between editable areas, when property names are not editable why move focus on it isn't ?

Comment: While the current solution moves between both label and editable area, if the focus in on label area as soon as you try to type something, the focus will be moved to edit area and you don't need to do anything else. Do we need any further try?

Comment: i think i am expecting too much from one answer, kudos man, atleast i got a way! marks your answer!

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the feedback, you also have my vote :)

Comment: To allow the tabs to start from the beginning again, I added this after the "if" `else if (entries.Count>0) {var next = entries[0]; next.Select(); return true;}`

Comment: Great answer! For others, if you want to handle forward = false    `if (!forward && index > 0)
            {
                var previous = entries[index - 1];
                previous.Select();
                return true;
            }`